# LEFT JOIN - losing a line from LEFT table selection

Tags: mysql, join

I have a trouble with the following query:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(t4.ItemID, 
IFNULL(t3.ItemID, IFNULL(t2.ItemID, t1.ItemID))) AS ID, 
IFNULL(t4.ParentItemID, 
IFNULL(t3.ParentItemID, 
IFNULL(t2.ParentItemID, t1.ParentItemID))) as Parent, 
IFNULL(tp4.ItemNo, IFNULL(tp3.ItemNo, IFNULL(tp2.ItemNo, tp1.ItemNo))) AS ItemNo
FROM ItemsParents AS t1
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP1 
ON t1.ItemID = tP1.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t2 
ON t1.ItemID = t2.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP2 
ON t2.ItemID = tP2.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t3 
ON t2.ItemID = t3.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP3 
ON t3.ItemID = tP3.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t4 
ON t3.ItemID = t4.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP4 
ON t4.ItemID = tP4.ID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = 
(
SELECT ID 
FROM ItemsDB 
WHERE ItemNoInt = 359
)
```

This table should return two rows (822 and 875) from the first part of selection and append more rows from following `ItemsParents LEFT JOINS`. It appends the new rows, but one row from the original two gets lost.
    822
    859
    834
    846
    810
...so **the row 875 got lost**.
If I remove or incapacitate the `LEFT JOIN` from parent items (by `"= 1 -- "` - commenting out the original condition):

```
SELECT IFNULL
(
t4.ItemID, 
IFNULL(t3.ItemID, IFNULL(t2.ItemID, t1.ItemID))) AS ID, 
IFNULL(t4.ParentItemID, 
IFNULL(t3.ParentItemID, 
IFNULL(t2.ParentItemID, t1.ParentItemID))) as Parent, 
IFNULL(tp4.ItemNo, 
IFNULL(tp3.ItemNo, IFNULL(tp2.ItemNo, tp1.ItemNo))) AS ItemNo
FROM ItemsParents AS t1
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP1 
ON t1.ItemID = tP1.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t2 
ON t1.ItemID = 1 -- t2.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP2 
ON t2.ItemID = tP2.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t3 
ON t2.ItemID = 1 -- t3.ParentItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP3 
ON t3.ItemID = tP3.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemsParents AS t4   -- t4.ParentItemID
ON t3.ItemID = 1 
LEFT JOIN ItemsDB AS tP4 
ON t4.ItemID = tP4.ID
WHERE t1.ParentItemID = 
(
SELECT ID 
FROM ItemsDB 
WHERE ItemNoInt = 359
)
```

...I returns correct two rows from left joined table (822 and 875).

I googled cases of lost rows in left joined table, but none of them seems to apply to this case. Any idea?

Regards,

Libor

Comment: Can you add some test data please?

Comment: Yes you can use outer apply, inside that sort desc using order by & select top 1. Can you share create script & sample data, here or on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Can you re-create this scenario via SQLFiddle.com? Are you saying the actually quantity of returned rows decrease?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you might want to use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) instead of IFNULL.

Comment: AgRizzo, I constructed the query in Navicat for MySQL and it behaves the same in VB.NET... There's no error message, so I assume it is really a query problem.

Comment: Vatev, thanks for suggestions, it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just IDEA, I hope you have asked for Finding last row of table in left join,

```
select LastRowofSubTable.* from tableMain
outer apply
(
    select top 1 * from tableSub
    where tableMain.id = tableSub.id
    order by tableSub.pk_id desc
)as LastRowofSubTable
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, that is why I mentioned IDEA, actually I am not familiar with MYSql. Also question is not fully clear.

Comment: Hmm, I think this will not apply to MySQL, though I will have to have a better look and test it. This would be a workaround and I feel there has to be a reason in the query it self for the faulty result. Please let me know what is not clear? I will clarify it in the text...